# Package is not properly installed in Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe, libgpiod

I'm building a custom Linux image with yocto and I'm attemping to add "libgpiod" package to the image built.
The `libgpiod` recipe is located at

```
project/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/libgpiod
```

and in the same location I have a `.bbappend` file that add some extra configuration.
The `.bbappend` is just a single line of code that enables cxx bindings:

```
PACKAGECONFIG += "cxx"
```

The problem that I'm facing is that in my  Linux image I'm not able to find `gpiod.h` nor `gpiod.hpp` (cxx bindings).

I know `libgpiod` is being compiled and added because I have the tools and the core available in the image (I can use `gpiodetect` that is an utility from gpiod), so I assume that yocto finds the recipe successfully.

Within my `bblayers.conf` file:

```
BBLAYERS = " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale-3rdparty \
  ${BSP
```

Note:
If I modify my `.bbappend` file to:

```
PACKAGECONFIG += "python3"
```

It compiles and add python3 bindings to the image, so I dont know why it doesnt work with cxx.

Reference:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/about/

Thanks!

I tried adding a `.bbappend` file with "cxx" configuration and it doesnt work.

Comment: The header files are supposed to be part of the `-dev` package, which are usually not installed in the image, but are part of the SDK, that can be used to develop applications.

Comment: IMAGE_INSTALL += "libgpiod"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you said:

> and in the same location I have a .bbappend file that add some extra
> configuration

This is really really NOT recommended. It is not recommended to modify community and core layers directly, even if you are creating another separate `.bbappend` file.

If you want to update `PACKAGECONFIG` of `libgpiod` you can create the `bbappend` file in a custom layer:

```
bitbake-layers create-layer meta-custom
bitbake-layers add-layer meta-custom
recipetool newappend meta-custom libgpiod
```

This will create a `bbappend` file for your, then put `PACKAGECONFIG` in it.

If you don't want that, just set it in `local.conf`:

```
PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-libgpiod = " cxx"
```

Now, goind back to the real issue here.

`libpiod` provides multiple packages:

- `libgpiod` containing `libgpiod.so*` files
- `libgpiod-dev` containing `/usr/include` for the header files and `/usr/lib` for the shared lib's `solink` file and corresponding `pkgconfig` metadata.
- `libgpiod-tools` containing `gpiodetect`, `gpioget`, ...

If you add `libgpiod` only to `IMAGE_INSTALL`, you will get only the shared libraries. Since you said that the tools are already there, it means somewhere somehow `libgpiod-tools` is getting added.

You propably need:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libgpiod-dev"
```

**EDIT** on how to check packages contents:

To know the content of all packages created by `libgpiod` recipe run:

```
bitbake-getvar -r libgpiod --value PKGDEST | xargs tree
```

Comment: Thanks, " libgpiod-dev" was the solution. Although I still have some doubts.  How did you know about libgpiod-dev and its content?, Where can I find info about how this package is organized? I read the whole official docs and cant even find a reference to libgpiod-dev.

Comment: Check **EDIT** in my response.

Comment: Pretty useful! Thank you so much Sir